# Using Drupal 7 views, merge data fields from 2 content types to a single row

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-views, relationship

I've been searching for a few days for a solution without any luck.

Here is the setup:

```
TV Shows (vocabulary): show-1, show-2, show-3, ...

Episodes (content type)            Schedule (content type)
  - title                            - date/time episode airs
  - episode code <.................> - episode code
  - reference to TV Show term
```

1) First I am trying to create a "view" that takes and argument of a "TV Show" term (or id), and based on that, lists out all episodes associated to that show AND when those episodes will be airing in the future.

One big problem is that nodes of content type "schedule" are not linked to a TV Show, so all of these are excluded right off the bat. Is there a way to show all "schedules" that are linked to an episode based on the input?

2) The second part to this puzzle is to go the other way, meaning Views is given a day and then lists out all schedule nodes that fall within that day. And since each schedule node contains an "episode code" which links back to an "episode", get the corresponding information from the "episode" node with a matching "episode code".

It almost sounds as if both of these scenarios require two separate views combined together, but is that even possible?

**Note:** When I say the "episode code" links the two content types, there is not a true link. I tried having just a text field in both content types labeled "episode code". I have also tried creating a vocabulary "episode" that had episode codes for for terms and then had both content types contain a field for the "episode" vocabulary.

Answer (score 3):

When you're creating one of those views (either the one to display all the episodes given a taxonomy or the one to show all episodes for a given time) -- and yes, those do sounds like two separate views -- just make sure you expand the '**Advanced**' section of the view.  Go ahead and add a '**Relationship**' so that you can get to the fields of the referenced content type.

For example, let's say you're creating your first view.  In that case it will be a view of episodes and you will use the presence of a taxonomy term as a **filter**.  In order to be able to display both 1) fields that exist in the episode content type and 2) fields that exist in the referenced schedule content type, you must add the appropriate **Relationship** to the view.

1. In the view's 'Advanced' section, add the appropriate relationship.  It may say something like 'Entity Reference: Referenced Entity: A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_schedule.'  Select the one that matches the name of your reference field, since I'm just guessing that it's field_schedule here.
2. On the setup screen for that relationship, fill in something that will be easy for you to understand in the '**Identifier**' field, like "Referenced schedule node".
3. Now start adding the fields you want your view to return in the '**Fields**' section.
4. When you get to a field that is part of the referenced content type (not the episode content type you started working with), go ahead and select that this field uses the relationship you created in step 2 in the '**Relationship**' drop-down.  That'll be available in the second setup screen after you add that field.
5. Finally, use a 'table' display if you want them to look like the fields are all in one row.

Now Drupal will know that you're trying to display a field from the referenced node, not the current episode node it's looking at.

It's a little confusing but I hope it makes sense.  This is the way to link referenced nodes in view -- using Relationships.